# How to create a trigger that creates a database object

Tags: mysql, database

I have in the database, some objects that are changing the need to create other objects (they store information about the change). It is planned to write a trigger that will catch the change and create a different object. How to do it?

Comment: You need to provide way more information about your problem and/or goals than you currently do. Your question is unclear as it is.

Comment: I use a MySQL database. And I just need a trigger to create another object (posuti it will be the object of another table).

Comment: Okay, show us how these databases/database-tables look like.

Comment: You cannot issue DDL commands (such as create table) from a trigger.

Comment: I do not need to create a table, but only one line of the table

Comment: Do you mean you want to update a table row?

Comment: No, I want a change of one line to create other, and in the other table. And I get that this line will be created carry the information about the changes that have taken place in the first row!

Comment: on update table_a insert into table_b?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do!

Comment: I can't improve on the mysql documentation - do you have a specific problem - what have you tried.